# Медиагруппа

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать МЕДИАГРУППА: слитно, раздельно или через дефис?

Answer (score 2):

**Медиа**... - первая часть сложных слов, пишется слитно (Орфографический словарь под ред. Лопатина). Соответственно, нужно писать **медиагруппа**.